# Why does my ruby regexp match never stop?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a trouble with a regexp I wrote in ruby:

```
reg = /\([^\(|\)]{5,}*\)/i #almost 5 caracters inside two parenthesis.
one_string = "(  foobarbaz, foobarbaz  "
one_string.match(reg)#works fine and return nil

one_string = "(  foobarbaz, foobarbaz,  foobarbaz, foobarbaz foobarbaz, foobarbaz, foobarbaz, foobarbaz  foobarbaz "
one_string.match(reg) # never stop if one_string is to long.
```

The parenthesis is not closed in `one_string`. And if the string I want to match is long, the match function does not seem to stop. Should I write my regexp differently, or is there a trouble with ruby (the expression is simple)?

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect here, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: *caracters* => characters. *two parenthesis* => two parentheses. *never stop* => never stops

Comment: An incorrect syntax would not compile, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression syntax is incorrect here.

```
\(               # match '('
[^\(|\)]{5,}     # match any character except: '\(', '|', '\)' (at least 5 times)
```

Then it fails on the `*` quantifier because the preceding token is not quantifiable. Also you can drop the `i` flag since you are not matching any word characters in your regular expression.

I am not clear on what you are exactly trying to do here, but you may be looking for something like this.

```
reg = /\([^()]{5,}\)?/
```

Which I still don't understand the concept, if you are just trying to match everything between:

```
reg = /\([^()]*\)?/
```

Explanation:

```
\(        # match '('
[^()]*    # any character except: '(', ')' (0 or more times)
\)?       # ')' (optional)
```

Comment: Ho yeah, sorry :-(. This is old code that worked fine in my tests. That's the reason why I did not inspect the syntax of my regex. It is better with `/\([^\(|\)]{5,}\)/i`.
I my code, the goal is not to directly match patterns, I only want to remove patterns witch contains more than 5 characters inside parentheses :
`foo bar (foo) (foo bar baz) bar` must give  `foo bar (foo)  bar`

Comment: `str.gsub(/\([^)]{5,}\)/, '')`